# Can I execute 1 python script by 3 different caller process at same time with respective arguments

Tags: python-3.x, centos

I have situation in centos where 3 different/Independent caller will try to execute same python script with respective command line args. eg: `python main.py arg1`, `python main.py arg2`, `python main.py arg3` at same time.

My question is - Is it possible in the first place or I need to copy that python script, 3 times with 3 different names to be called by each process.

If it is possible then how it should be done so that these 3 processes will not interfare and python script execution will be independent from each other.

Comment: Did you try to do it? Was there a particular problem?

Comment: I can't try this, because I am automating checkpoint firewall web services at client side. So I need to have some background on this as It would create serious issues in their firewall. I am using graylog to trigger these scripts.

Answer (score 1):

All the python processes will run entirely isolated from each other, even if executing the same source file.

If they interact with any external resource other than process memory (such as files on disk), then you may need to take measures to make sure the processes don't interfere (by making sure each instance uses a different filename, for example).

Comment: Thank you !! @Rob